# Symfony content is always null

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, symfony

I have a Symfony2 project but I'm totally lost. I want to be able to get the comment.
On my server side I have:

```
 /**
 *
 * @Get("/{communeId}/room/{roomId}/booked/time/", requirements={"communeId" : "\d+", "roomId" : "\d+"})
 * @param int     $communeId
 * @param int     $roomId
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  resource=false,
 *  description="See if room is available",
 *  statusCodes={
 *         204="Returned when deleted successfully",
 *         401="Returned when you are not authorized",
 *  },
 * )
 *
 * @Rest\View()
 *
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function getRoomBookingAvailableAction($communeId, $roomId, Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true)['comment'];
    return View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setData($data)
        ->setSerializationContext(
            SerializationContext::create()
                ->enableMaxDepthChecks()
                ->setGroups(array("detail", "commune", "reservationItemDetail"))
        );
}
```

On the client side I have:

```
//Refresh the current booking, check for exclusiondates and handle errors
$scope.refreshBooking = function () {
  API.get('api/v1/booking/' + $scope.bookingId).success(function (response) {
    $scope.booking = response;
    $scope.multiply($scope.booking.exclusionDates);
    $scope.dayIds = [];
    $scope.getDayIds($scope.booking.exclusionDays);
    $scope.datesBetween = $scope.getDates($scope.selectedDays[0], $scope.selectedDays[1]);

  });
    //Kijk of de datum niet al geboekt is.
   // if($scope.booking.roomReservations.length>0){
        API.get('api/v1/commune/'+ $cookieStore.get('TangoCommuneId') +'/room/4/booked/time/',{'comment':"comment"}).success(function (response){
            console.log(response);
        }).error(function (err){
            console.log(err);
        });

};
```

For usings I have:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Post;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Delete;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Patch;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

the refresh booking function works. As it should however. When I do the API.get call with ,{'comment':"comment"}. The comment is always empty? I have the exact same thing. Working so I'm really confused. I just want the request to receive this comment var. And make it possible to get it on the server side. Been at it all day. Really can't see whats wrong and why comment is always null. I find it really strange. So I really do not understand why my server does not have this comment. I have tried ,{'comment' : "comment"}

> console.log(response); gives me ""

The server responses with success.

Comment: Do you know for certain that actual action is being fired?

Comment: Yes because I putted a throw new.... in before. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparntly, When I use a GET call. I cannot provide params to the call only when I use Patch Or Post.